# Application of arguments to function composition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, function-composition, pointfree

Being a newbie to Haskell I can’t understand why the expression
`head . words “one two three four”` throws an exception and function composition `head . words` must be applied with `$` operator - the expression on the right of it doesn’t need further evaluation because it’s just a single `String`. The other way to compile it is to put `head . words` in parentheses but `(head . words) :: String -> String` has the same type as `head . words :: String -> String` so why putting it in parentheses makes the expression compile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of precedence rules. Application has highest precedence; `$` - lowest.

`head . words “one two three four”` is parsed as `head . (words “one two three four”)` i.e. `words` applied on a string must produce a function (as demanded by `(.)`). But that's not the type that `words` has:

```
Prelude> :t words
words :: String -> [String]
```

`head . words $ “one two three four”` on the other hand, is parsed as `(head . words) “one two three four”` and the types fit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a bit difficult for me to grasp that the composition operator is itself a function.

Comment: @wojtek ah, yes, `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. Don't forget, arrows in type signatures associate to the right. It's really `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`. Imagine you've got these two pipes, `g :: b->c` and `h :: a->b`. So obviously, `b` output goes into the `b` input: `(g.h)x = g (h x)` i.e. `(g.h) :: a->c`.

Comment: @wojtek Every operator is itself a function, and has lower precedence than function application. This is something a Haskell programmer absolutely must keep in mind.